# ListFragment not displaying data

Tags: java, android

I can't figure out why the data is not being shown in the list view. It is storing it to the Array list, because when I check to see if it is null, it returns false (meaning that it has information).

Main Activity:

```
package com.goldleaf.branden.goldleafcomics;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    ListView lvGlimpse;
    public List<UniverseListing>universalListings = new ArrayList<UniverseListing>();

    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "http://goldleafcomics.com/application/UniverseGlimpse.JSON";
        PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Application Data Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                GlimpseListFragment glimpse = new GlimpseListFragment();
                glimpse.makeList(s);
            }
        });
        task.execute(url);

        GlimpseListFragment fragment = new GlimpseListFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Goldleaf Comics!");
        
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_news) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("G.C. News");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_team) {
            TeamFeedFragment fragment = new TeamFeedFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Team Feed");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }else if(id == R.id.nav_notifications){
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Notifications");
        }else if(id == R.id.nav_comics){
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Comics");
        }else if(id == R.id.nav_glimpse){
            GlimpseListFragment fragment = new GlimpseListFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Glimpse");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The fragment that is not showing the list:

```
package com.goldleaf.branden.goldleafcomics;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GlimpseListFragment extends ListFragment {
    List<String> glimpse = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<UniverseListing> universalListings = new ArrayList<UniverseListing>();

    public GlimpseListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(UniverseListing value: universalListings){
            titles.add(value.universeId);
        }

        ArrayList<String> glimpse = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(UniverseListing value: universalListings){
            glimpse.add(value.universeGlimpse);
        }

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_glimpse_list, container, false);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, glimpse);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id){
        String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), glimpse.indexOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void makeList(String r){
        ArrayList<UniverseListing> universalListings = new JsonConverter<UniverseListing>().toArrayList(r, UniverseListing.class);
        if(universalListings == null){
            Log.w("Glimpse", "no information");
        }else{
            Log.w("Glimpse", "information stored");
        }
    }
}
```

UniverseListing:

```
package com.goldleaf.branden.goldleafcomics;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class UniverseListing {
    @SerializedName("universe_id")
    public String universeId;

    @SerializedName("universe_glimpse")
    public String universeGlimpse;

    @SerializedName("universe_url")
    public String universeuRL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess two problems,
1. makelist call is made on new instance of fragment which is not attached to UI.
2. notifydatasetchagned is not called in makelist, once the data is modified.

Can you try with below changes:
1. In Activity, use the same fragment instance instead of creating new Fragment instance

```
            //GlimpseListFragment glimpse = new GlimpseListFragment();
         // use the previously created instance, which is attached to UI
            glimpse.makeList(s);
```

Dont create new, better put this code after committing the fragment.

2. call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the makeList() function.

Comment: it doesnt allow me to comment out and use the attached ui because it defined after the method, not before. and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() also isnt available in the makeList() function

Comment: I put final GlimpseListFragment glimpse = new GlimpseListFragment(); so it using the same instance and data is being stored, its still not displaying

Comment: ok. since here arrayadapter is used, can try setting a new Adapter in makeList() and the  setListAdapter(adapter) again in makeList